# tic-tac-toe game with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm to build a tic-tac-toe game using html, css and javascript. I have tried everything I Know, but it seems there's error in my js code. i'll appreciate if anybody can help me spot where the error is in my js code.
once i clicked in any of the boxes, the first mark should be X then O, then X and O will continue to trade off until there is a winner. A winner emerged when u have the same mark in a row or column or diagonal.
here is my js code:

```js
const upperLeft = document.getElementById("first-up").querySelector("span");
const upperCenter = document.getElementById("second-up").querySelector("span");
const upperRight = document.getElementById("third-up").querySelector("span");
const middleLeft = document.getElementById("first-middle").querySelector("span");
const middleCenter = document.getElementById("second-middle").querySelector("span");
const middleRight = document.getElementById("third-middle").querySelector("span");
const bottomLeft = document.getElementById("first-bottom").querySelector("span");
const bottomCenter = document.getElementById("second-bottom").querySelector("span");
const bottomRight = document.getElementById("third-bottom").querySelector("span");
let addCross = true;

const allDivs = document.getElementById("game-container");
const allSpans = allDivs.querySelectorAll("span");


for (const p of allSpans) {
  p.addEventListener("click", addPlayer);
}

function addPlayer(e) {
  const boxTarget = e.target.innerText;

  if (boxTarget !== "*") {
    return;
  }

  boxTarget.classList.remove("cross");
  boxTarget.classList.remove("circle");

  if (addCross) {
    boxTarget.innerText = "X";
    boxTarget.classList.add("cross");
    addCross = false;
  } else {
    boxTarget.innerText = "O";
    boxTarget.ClassList.add("circle");
    addCross = true;
  }
  setTimeout(confirmWinner, 100);
}

//if there is no winner
function checkAllMarked() {
  const box1 = upperLeft.innerText;
  const box2 = upperCenter.innerText;
  const box3 = upperRight.innertext;
  const box4 = middleLeft.innerText;
  const box5 = middleCenter.innerText;
  const box6 = middleRight.innerText;
  const box7 = bottomLeft.innerText;
  const box8 = bottomCenter.innerText;
  const box9 = bottomRight.innerText;

  if (box1 !== "*" && box2 !== "*" &&
    box3 !== "*" && box4 !== "*" &&
    box5 !== "*" && box6 !== "*" &&
    box7 !== "*" && box8 !== "*") {

    alert("Cat's game!");
    resetGame();
  }
}

function confirmWinner() {
  const box1 = upperLeft.innerText;
  const box2 = upperCenter.innerText;
  const box3 = upperRight.innertext;
  const box4 = middleLeft.innerText;
  const box5 = middleCenter.innerText;
  const box6 = middleRight.innerText;
  const box7 = bottomLeft.innerText;
  const box8 = bottomCenter.innerText;
  const box9 = bottomRight.innerText;

  //first horizontal line
  if (box1 === box2 && box1 === box3 && box2 === box3 && box1 !== "*") {
    alert(box1 + "" + won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //second horizontal line
    if (box4 === box5 && box4 === box6 && box5 === box6 && bo4 !== "*") {
      alert(box4 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //third horizontal line
    if (box7 === box8 && box7 === box9 && box8 === box9 && bo7 !== "*") {
      alert(box7 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //first vertical column
    if (box1 === box4 && box1 === box7 && box4 === box7 && bo1 !== "*") {
      alert(bo1 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //second vertical row
    if (box2 === box5 && box2 === box8 && box5 === box8 && bo2 !== "*") {
      alert(box2 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //third vertical row
    if (box3 === box6 && box3 === box9 && box6 === box9 && bo3 !== "*") {
      alert(box3 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //first diagonal
    if (box1 === box5 && box1 === box9 && box5 === box9 && bo1 !== "*") {
      alert(box1 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;
    }

    //second diagonal
    if (box3 === box5 && box3 === box7 && box5 === box7 && bo3 !== "*") {
      alert(box3 + "" + "won!");
      resetGame();
      return;

    }

    checkAllMarked();

  }

  function resetGame() {
    upperLeft.innerText = "*";
    upperCenter.innerText = "*";
    upperRight.innertext = "*";
    middleLeft.innerText = "*";
    middleCenter.innerText = "*";
    middleRight.innerText = "*";
    bottomLeft.innerText = "*";
    bottomCenter.innerText = "*";
    bottomRight.innerText = "*";

    allSpans.classList.remove("cross", "circle");
    addCross = true;
  }
```

```css
#game-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.boxes {
  font-family: sans-serif, Crimson Pro;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

#first-up {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}

#second-up {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

#third-up {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

#first-middle {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

#second-middle {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}

#third-middle {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

#first-bottom {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}

#second-bottom {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

#third-bottom {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.cross {
  color: red;
}

span.circle {
  color: black;
}
```

html codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tic-tac-toe game</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "events.css">
</head>

    <body>
    <h2 align= "center">The Tic-tac-toe Game</h2>
    
    <div id="game-container">
    
        <div id="first-up" class ="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="second-up" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="third-up" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="first-middle" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="second-middle" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="third-middle" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        
        <div id="first-bottom" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="second-bottom" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="third-bottom" class="boxes">
            <span class= "space">*</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src= "events.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Your html code is empty. Where is whole your DOM structure? Please past whole your html file

Comment: alert(box1 + "" + won!");  is wrong one "to many i think it should be  alert(box1 + " won!");

Comment: i think you copied this somewhere since you'r emissing some stuff.. next error will be because teher is no player element, boxTarget is the value of this player value, but its not there..  use F12 in your browser to check for errors and fix them 1 by 1

Comment: @Rmaxx thanks. i added +"" in order to add space, but d correction is noted.

Comment: i didnt copy the whole code. after highlighting the functions i needed, i google some answers online, such as how to target and get text etc. i'll use f12 and see if i will be able to debug the errors. thanks

Comment: @DamianKrólak i have edited the question to display the html codes properly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, i have been able to debug the code. i have tested it and it gives the expected result. here is my code:

```
const upperLeft = document.getElementById("first-up").querySelector("span");
const upperCenter = document.getElementById("second-up").querySelector("span");
const upperRight = document.getElementById("third-up").querySelector("span");
const middleLeft = document.getElementById("first-middle").querySelector("span");
const middleCenter = document.getElementById("second-middle").querySelector("span");
const middleRight = document.getElementById("third-middle").querySelector("span");
const bottomLeft = document.getElementById("first-bottom").querySelector("span");
const bottomCenter = document.getElementById("second-bottom").querySelector("span");
const bottomRight = document.getElementById("third-bottom").querySelector("span");
let addCross = true;

const allDivs = document.getElementById("game-container");
const allSpans = allDivs.querySelectorAll("span");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for(const p of allSpans){
    p.addEventListener("click", addPlayer);
}
});

function addPlayer(e){
    const boxTarget = e.target;
    
    if(boxTarget.innerText !== "*"){
        return;
    }
    
    boxTarget.classList.remove("cross");
    boxTarget.classList.remove("circle");
    
    if(addCross){
        boxTarget.innerText= "X";
        boxTarget.classList.add("cross");
        addCross = false;
    } else{
        boxTarget.innerText= "O";
        boxTarget.classList.add("circle");
        addCross = true;
    }
    setTimeout(confirmWinner, 100);
}


function confirmWinner(){
    const box1 = upperLeft.innerText;
    const box2 = upperCenter.innerText;
    const box3 = upperRight.innerText;
    const box4 = middleLeft.innerText;
    const box5 = middleCenter.innerText;
    const box6 = middleRight.innerText;
    const box7 = bottomLeft.innerText;
    const box8 = bottomCenter.innerText;
    const box9 = bottomRight.innerText;
    
    //first horizontal line
    if(box1===box2 && box2 ===box3 && box1===box3 && box1!== "*"){
        alert(box1 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
        
    }
    
        //second horizontal line
     if(box4===box5 && box5===box6 && box4===box6 && box4!=="*"){
        alert(box4 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
    }
    
    //third horizontal line
     if(box7===box8 && box8===box9 && box7===box9 && box7!=="*"){
        alert(box7 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
    }
    
    //first vertical column
     if(box1===box4 && box4===box7 && box1===box7 && box1!=="*"){
        alert(box1 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;  
    }
    
    //second vertical row
     if(box2===box5 && box5===box8 && box2===box8 && box2!=="*"){
        alert(box2 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
    }
    
    //third vertical row
     if(box3===box6 && box6===box9 && box3===box9 && box3!=="*"){
        alert(box3 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
    }
    
    //first diagonal
     if(box1===box5 && box5===box9 && box1===box9 && box1!=="*"){
        alert(box1 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;
    }
    
    //second diagonal
     if(box3===box5 && box5===box7 && box3===box7 && box3!=="*"){
        alert(box3 + " won!");
        resetGame();
        return;     
    } 
    
    checkAllMarked();   
    
}   
    
    //if there is no winner
    function checkAllMarked(){
        const box1 = upperLeft.innerText;
        const box2 = upperCenter.innerText;
        const box3 = upperRight.innertext;
        const box4 = middleLeft.innerText;
        const box5 = middleCenter.innerText;
        const box6 = middleRight.innerText;
        const box7 = bottomLeft.innerText;
        const box8 = bottomCenter.innerText;
        const box9 = bottomRight.innerText;
        
        if(box1 !=="*" && box2!=="*" &&
        box3!== "*" && box4!== "*" &&
        box5 !== "*" && box6!== "*" &&
        box7!== "*" && box8!== "*"){
            
            alert("Cat's game!");
            resetGame();
        }
    }
    
function resetGame(){
    upperLeft.innerText = "*";
    upperCenter.innerText = "*";
    upperRight.innerText = "*";
    middleLeft.innerText = "*";
    middleCenter.innerText = "*";
    middleRight.innerText = "*";
    bottomLeft.innerText = "*";
    bottomCenter.innerText = "*";
    bottomRight.innerText = "*";
    
    upperLeft.classList.remove("cross");
    upperCenter.classList.remove("cross");
    upperRight.classList.remove("cross");
    middleLeft.classList.remove("cross");
    middleCenter.classList.remove("cross");
    middleRight.classList.remove("cross");
    bottomLeft.classList.remove("cross");
    bottomCenter.classList.remove("cross");
    bottomRight.classList.remove("cross");
    
    upperLeft.classList.remove("circle");
    upperCenter.classList.remove("circle");
    upperRight.classList.remove("circle");
    middleLeft.classList.remove("circle");
    middleCenter.classList.remove("circle");
    middleRight.classList.remove("circle");
    bottomLeft.classList.remove("circle");
    bottomCenter.classList.remove("circle");
    bottomRight.classList.remove("circle");
    
    addCross= true;
}
```